# Tax implications of elective dual US/AU citizenship

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, australia, citizenship

I am a US citizen born in the US to an American mother and Australian father. I am eligible to apply for Australian citizenship via [citizenship by descent](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Citi/pathways-processes/application-options/descent).

I live and work entirely in the US and plan to live and work in the US for the next few years.

What are the tax implications if I decide to get Australian citizenship in this manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a tax professional, but AFAIK this would have no effect on your current tax situation. The IRS just classifies people as tax residents or not- citizenship or even documented/undocumented status doesn't matter. (The difference is that permanent residents and citizens are automatically tax residents, whereas there's a 183-day residency rule for all other people.) So your U.S. tax burden wouldn't change at all.

Well, what about Australia? Like all sane countries, they don't tax income of people who don't live there. So no issues with that.

In fact, there are only two countries that do tax non-resident income- the U.S. and Eritrea. So the only way this could affect your tax situation is if you move abroad (to Australia or elsewhere) and renounce your U.S. citizenship to avoid continuing to pay those taxes.